# Magento 2 - Update modules without shop throwing exception

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3, extensions, composer

I upgraded my modules by calling `composer update`, then my shop was going offline with the message:

> Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the
>   Magento root directory.

Is this showing because my magento is in "developer" mode? Will this exception also show if I am in "production" mode?

I fear that I can only update my modules in 4:30 o'clock in the morning when there is almost no traffic on my shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not because of the developer mode and Yes this will also happen on your production if you did `composer update` or take pull of this code-base

Here is bit of explanation,

`bin/magento setup:upgrade` is **required** when module version in code-base is different to that module's version in database

`bin/magento setup:upgrade` will run **install-update(schema/data)** and then update module version in database.

Comment: So is there no way to update your modules without the shop throwing an exception and being offline? I wonder how big shops like Amazon are doing this.

Comment: I don't think so, you can enable maintenance flag while doing this, on frontend customers will see under maintenance page till you process all this

Comment: Thats a very bad software design by magento. They could make the shop use the old extension until you upgrade the database, to prevent any exceptions... Thanks

Comment: Its not that bad, just you have to follow a process, if you have time here are some interesting link to read, https://inviqa.com/blog/how-achieve-zero-downtime-deployments-magento-2, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75458/how-to-avoid-site-downtime-on-module-install, these are not full-proof techniques but can minimize your downtime.

Comment: It is bad, because it should work without any downtime at all, like at Amazon or other big shops.